# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Cell found

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

I try to use xlrd to load some records from excel and check the relationship. 
Please refer to my amateur codes for more details:

```
import xlrd

feature_list_file = xlrd.open_workbook('FeatureList.xls')
feature_table = feature_list_file.sheet_by_index(0)

num_feature_rows = feature_table.nrows
num_feature_cols = feature_table.ncols

feature_list = []

for i in range(num_feature_rows):
    feature_list.append(feature_table.cell(i, 1))
# print feature_list

issue_list_file = xlrd.open_workbook('IssueList.xls')
issue_table = issue_list_file.sheet_by_index(0)

num_issue_rows = issue_table.nrows
num_issue_cols = issue_table.ncols

epic_list = []

for i in range(num_issue_rows):
    if issue_table.cell(i, 0).value == 'Epic':
        epic_list.append(issue_table.cell(i, 1).value)

# print epic_list


def check_link(actual_link, parent_list):
    result = True
    for i in range(parent_list.__len__()):
        count = 0
        if parent_list[i] in actual_link:
            count += 1
            if count > 1:
                result = False
                break
    return result


invalid_list = []

for i in range(num_issue_rows):
    if issue_table.cell(i, 10).value == '':
        invalid_list.append(issue_table.cell(i, 1).value)
    else:
        if issue_table.cell(i, 0).value == 'Story':
            if check_link(issue_table.cell(i, 10).value, epic_list):
                invalid_list.append(issue_table.cell(i, 1).value)
        if issue_table.cell(i, 0).value == 'Epic':
            if check_link(issue_table.cell(i, 10).value, feature_list):
                invalid_list.append(issue_table.cell(i, 1).value)

print invalid_list
```

However, it always returns below messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sut/PycharmProjects/ItemChecker/JiraItemChecker.py", line 54, in <module>
    if check_link(issue_table.cell(i, 10).value, feature_list):
  File "/Users/sut/PycharmProjects/ItemChecker/JiraItemChecker.py", line 36, in check_link
    if parent_list[i] in actual_link:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Cell found
```

How could I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason your `check_link` function isn't just `return actual_link in parent_list` ?

Comment: `for i in range(parent_list.__len__()):`  ... really??????

Comment: @Jon Clements, because actual_link might be a long string which contains more than 1 item of parent_list...

Comment: @SUT okay, any reason to not use `any(pl in actual_link for pl in parent_list)` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to do an `in` on an `xlrd.cell` object, I think you need to change

```
if parent_list[i] in actual_link:
```

to

```
if parent_list[i].value in actual_link:
```

adding some more details to my answer based on your comment

Your call is passing what appears to be a string and a list of cells
the string is fine, but in your function you iterate over the list and try to compare each instance of the cell class to the correctly passed string, and there's your problem.

hope this helps (and I'm not misreading the code!)

and some more details -

here's the crux of the problem, when you create the `feature_list`, and the `epic_list` you are doing it in 2 different ways, on the first you are appending a cell to the list, on the second you are appending a value.  BUT then you are using the same `check_link` function on both types.  So either you need to extend your `check_link` function to handle both types, OR you need to be consistent and pick one.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply. Actually, I have used .value while invoking the function, check_link(issue_table.cell(i, 10).value, epic_list).

I also add .value again, it returns "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'value'"

Comment: no you are using .value in the wrong place, you need to add it to the element in the list you are iterating over, not to the value you are looking for

Comment: I edit the codes according your answer, however, it returns AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'value' ...

Comment: can you add a small sample of what your data looks like?  I created a simple set of 2 xls files and ran your code on it and it seemed to work (at least it didn't throw any errors)

Comment: I take that back - after playing around with the data a bit I was able to replicate the exception, and once I added a .value as I put in my initial answer it worked (ok, I had to play with the data some more here but...).  In any case if you can get a set of sample sheets onto SO I'll be happy to take another look, but if you can't (for whatever reason) I don't think I can do anything else.  Good luck!

Comment: Please download the data files from the url which could be found in the original question...

Comment: blocked at work :(  If my most recent update (I added it to my original answer) doesn't answer your question I'll try to take a look at home over the weekend

Comment: After update my codes with your answer, it works now... Thanks a ton !!